# Oracle ODI string literal mapping

Tags: java, excel, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I'm looking into whether or not Oracle ODI has some capability needed by my organization for an ETL(ELT) operation.

We need to be able to create pairs of string literals for mapping an input string literal from a data source (Excel file), to a different string literal in a data target (Oracle table).

For example:

> Excel File Gender Column value: "M"

becomes

> Oracle Table Gender Column Value: "Male"

after the ELT.

Does Oracle ODI have this capability?

Comment: It should given the content here http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dit/odi/key_feature

Comment: Let me know what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, you can do it.

ODI allows you to choose Microsoft Excel as a Data Source (I am not sure if it allows for `.xlsx` format, I have not tried either).

You have to map your Excel sheet as a input, and it can fetch data from that sheet, once you have the data in your Staging/Temp table you can do the Transformation a whatever you like and insert the records into your Final table.

Follow [this link](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/05/tutorial-20-load-ms-excel-data-in-oracle-using-odi/) for just a reference and try to Google step - by - step as you move further to get answers for specific questions.